# -normative word for practices and institutions that privilege or value being a parent?

Tags: terminology

Is there a *-normative* word like *heteronormative* or *mononormative* for practices and institutions that privilege or value being a parent as fundamental or 'normal' within society? I suggest *parentonormative*.

Comment: Pro-parent? Or parent/family-friendly.

Comment: thanks Stuart... I'm getting at a term that carries the same sense of passive privileging (being a parent as opposed to not) as "heteronormative" carries for privileging heterosexual relationships. Pro-parent is more active, and family-friendly is too general and too ambiguous.

Comment: I've never heard such a term. Your suggested term would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

The word **natalism** (or **pronatalism**) is fairy close. [As Wikipedia states:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalism)

> **Natalism** (also called **pronatalism** or the **pro-birth** position) is an ideology that promotes the reproduction of human life as an important objective of being human and advocates high birthrate.